# Azure Bastion Service

Tags: azure, azure-bastion

Can we use Azure Bastion to login to a Azure AD joined Windows 10 device using my AAD credentials?
I am consistently getting the error 'The username or password is incorrect' whereas in reality it is correct. Login via RDP works.

Please help.

Comment: Unfotunately, Azure Bastopm doesn't support the AAD logins at this time. 

There is a discussion on the similar feature report here :  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/37961281-aad-integration

Comment: @SatyaV I hv a doubt.Bastion service can be activated only through the Azure Portal, right? We connect to our Azure Portal via AD login ofcourse, and then we go to initiate Bastion service to connect to our VM. For VM we use our service accounts to connect. Are we talking of this service accounts that we are using to connect to the VM here, that "Unfotunately, Azure Bastion doesn't support the AAD logins at this time." or is it something else?